# How can I know English flight times from Manchester airport?

Tags: air-travel, delays

I claimed for a flight which was delayed for over three hours but the airline are saying that the delay was only 2 hours and 31 minutes. The flight was Jet2 LS863 from Manchester to Murcia in Spain due to depart at 15:15 on the 25th July 2015. We didn't actually leave the ground until after 18:30.

Comment: You can use [FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/) (you may need to register), but looking back that flight didn't seem to run on 25th July 2015. The closest flight was on the [24th](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/EXS863/history/20150724/1615Z/EGCC/LELC) and was ahead of schedule ... are you sure about the date?

Comment: For EU261 claims, the key number is the delay to arrival, not the delay to departure. How late were you arriving into Spain?

Comment: Just a reminder that the **Arrival Time** in EU law corresponds to the
time at which **at least one of the doors of the aircraft is opened**, the assumption being that, at that moment, the passengers are permitted to leave the aircraft. You can check the _Case C-452/13 Germanwings_

Comment: Yes, but when did the plane push back from the gate? That's more likely to be considered the departure time.

Comment: @mkennedy The departure time is irrelevant for an EC 261/2004 claim. The importance is the arrival time.

Comment: What's an “English” flight time?